# Rails 2 + Delayed_job 2.0.7: Best way to automate the worker to start jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm researching and finding it hard to find a mainstream way to start the worker for the delayed_job gem. So far, I have one solution to use Capistrano:

```
# add this to config/deploy.rb
namespace :delayed_job do
  desc "Start delayed_job process"
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{current_path}; script/delayed_job start #{rails_env}"
  end

  desc "Stop delayed_job process"
  task :stop, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{current_path}; script/delayed_job stop #{rails_env}"
  end

  desc "Restart delayed_job process"
  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{current_path}; script/delayed_job restart #{rails_env}"
  end
end

after "deploy:start", "delayed_job:start"
after "deploy:stop", "delayed_job:stop"
after "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:restart"
```

but apparently there can be some cases where the Apache user is diferent from the Rails app user which will cause issues? Is there a better way to automate the worker process so that I don't have to sit at my comp and type

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop
```

all day in the console?

Comment: Can you explain a little better? do you want to manage delayed_job remotelly or locally from the server? what's the error when using capistrano? do you want some kind of restart or something done automatically on each deploy? it's not clear

Comment: @arieljuod no error, just wondering if there's a way to automate the starting and stopping of the worker. are there any cases where this capistrano method wouldn't work (issue of permission rights with apache and rails users?)

Answer (score 0):

I created a rake task to run " rake:jobs workoff " once daily. You can set as often as you need. I used heroku scheduler.